# Which programming language is good if I want to interact with motors programmatically?

Tags: rubiks-cube

I am working on making a program to solve the rubik's cube. 
I want to know how and which programming language should I learn so I could interact with real motors which will be used to turn the cube's sides according to algorithm.

Comment: You can use pretty much any language you want. The more important question is: What motors do you want to use and with what hardware do do you intend to control them (some Arduino platform, Lego Mindstorms, some PC interface card, ...)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solving a Rubiks cube would require you to have a camera set up, and some video processing going on; it's a dive straight into one of the hardest software topics. If you've never worked with physical devices from software before, you should start with something a bit simpler than a Rubiks cube solver.

Normally you get the motors and microcontroller first, and use the language that the microcontroller supports. Have a look at Arduino projects on Google, they have a whole range from beginner to expert, including Rubiks cube solvers.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll go with Arduino projects first, to get the insight of it all. 
PS- I am new to stack Overflow. My post got 2 downvotes. Am I doing something wrong? 
I'll appreciate it if someone could just tell me so I can improve in my future questions.

Comment: I think the expectation of any question on Stack Overflow is at least this: The question, what you have tried, what you were expecting, and what you got.

Comment: okay, I'll try to improve in future posts. Thanks for the advice and answer. :)

Comment: No problem. It's quite off-putting, when you get down voted for asking an unclear question simply because you are not an expert in that field... I've only asked a total of 4 questions on S.O, because I always imagine someone saying I could have found the answer on Google :P